# PhoneGap reading and writing files won't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to understand the file system of android with PhoneGap, but whatever I try, it won't really do much.
Here's an example I found on the internet (I changed console log to writing because I can't see the logs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileReader Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <div id="yay">Good: </div>
    <div id="aww">Bad: </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">



    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            document.getElementById('yay').innerHTML += "Read as data URL";
            document.getElementById('yay').innerHTML += evt.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            document.getElementById('yay').innerHTML += "Read as text";
            document.getElementById('yay').innerHTML += evt.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(evt) {
        document.getElementById('aww').innerHTML += evt.target.error.code;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Read File</p>
    <div id="yay"></div>
    <div id="aww"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I really hope you can help me! I need to write a certain file and read that later when the user has no internet, that's all really...
I checked all the wikis and stuff but the cordova github page really doesn't help, as far as I can see..

Answer (score 0):

Just found out about [this amazing API](https://github.com/poja/PhoneGap-FileAPI-Improved) by @YishaiG. Works perfectly: fixed my issues!